# Замена идентификаторов

Tags: php

Пытаюсь написать код который прощитывает шаблон из папки и выводит пользователю валидную страницу. Вот так выглядит шаблон:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{TITLE}</title>
    <meta name="description" content="{DESC}">
    <meta name="keywords" content="{KEYS}">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">

        <div class="topmenu">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                $%UPMENU%$
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="sidebar">
            $%SIDEBAR%$
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            $%CONTENT%$
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

$%UPMENU%$

$%SIDEBAR%$

$%CONTENT%$ - все это идентификаторы.

А теперь и сам вопрос: Как заменить каждый идентификатор кодом php?

Comment: чем вас уже имеющиеся шаблонизаторы не устраивают ?

Comment: да и вообще чем плохо вместо 

     $%SIDEBAR%$

писать 

     <?php include "sidebar.php"?>

Comment: Плохого ничего нет, это чисто в эстетических целях. И все же?

Comment: Я вот про что, вы по всей видимости хотите делать велосипед, и мало того вовлекаете в это велостроение других людей, задача делать парсер на php не интересная и сам php мало подходит под неё.

Comment: если вам очень хочется, просто используйте  [`preg_replace_callback();`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace-callback.php) - там все есть для вашей задачи

-----
в callback вставить функцию которая будет выполнять код в зависимости от идентификатора.

Comment: в callback ставить функцию в которой нужный мне скрипт?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте str_replace.

Я так понимаю планируется маленький шаблонизатор, если да то можно прочитать тут - http://larin.in/archives/16

Comment: Да, вы правы - будет шаблонизатор. Однако то, что по ссылке мне не подходит, так как мне требуется вместо строки вставить целый php скрипт...

Comment: @TheGunth прогоняйте скрипт, записывайте его в буфер (начать знакомство можно с [ob_start()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.ob-start.php)), заменяйте идентификатор шаблона на содержимое буфера, вот и все.